# log4j () getCurrentLoggers(log4j-1.2.16.jar) missing some loggers

Tags: spring-mvc, log4j

I am using log4j in the following way:

org.apache.log4j.LogManager.getCurrentLoggers() but it does not bring all the loggers that I have. Is there any special configuration for this? For instance, I create a Spring bean decorated with the @Service annotation and it finds it, but if it does not have the annotation then it does not show up.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Kind regards,
user1532449

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question...

Loggers were not being found because the classes containing them were not being instantiated. As soon as I created an instance of the class they were found by the LogManager.getCurrentLoggers() method.